# Key-value store for Node.js that works under Windows/Node 0.8

Tags: node.js, leveldb

I am working on a project that needs a fast, embedded and persistent key-value store (like LevelDB), but the development environment is restricted to Windows 7 / Node 0.8. My natural response was to try and find a LevelDB binding, but LevelUP / my8bird's leveldb do not compile under Windows at all, and LevelDOWN works only for Node.js > 0.10.

Any ideas? It doesn't **have** to be LevelDB - just any embedded (serverless) key-value store with persistence and reasonable crash-tolerance that has Node.js bindings that would work under that environment.

Comment: I don't know about the Node 0.8 / Windows 7 compatibility, but there's this: https://github.com/juliangruber/level-store

Comment: This depends on levelup, so it does not have compatibility.

Comment: You could try https://github.com/felixge/node-dirty

Answer (score 2):

`LMDB` builds/runs fine on Windows. http://symas.com/mdb/  It is also smaller, faster, and more reliable than LevelDB.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the "sqlite3" module compiles on Windows, so I built a simple key-value abstraction layer on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a port for [levelDB in Windows](https://code.google.com/r/kkowalczyk-leveldb/). I do not know if it is compatible with your specification. My question is why can't you update node.js because node v0.8 is at End-Of-Life(EOL). Maybe a pure Javascript clone, but maybe the performance will be a little less:

- https://github.com/mikesmullin/node-sqlite-purejs

Maybe not use embeddable database but something like MongoDB? Your requirements make it more difficult to find a solution if you ask me.

Comment: levelDB works on Windows but there aren't any Node.js bindings that compile on Windows.

And the actual application is not a server, so MongoDB would be impractical